# BottomSheetFragment + Frag with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm working with three classes - MainActivity, Frag1, BottomSheetFrag.
I'm sending an object from BottomSheet to Frag1, using a simple Interface, passing through MainAc. Which is perfectly functional. But when recyclerView set the adapter, i'm getting NullPointerException.

BottomSheet:

```
private EditText et_name;
private EditText et_contact;
private Button btn_ok;
ICommunic comm;

private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback
            mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN)
            dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

    }
};
@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
    View v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_BS, null);

    et_name = v.findViewById(R.id.et_nameV);
    et_contact = v.findViewById(R.id.et_contactV);
    btn_ok = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_save);

    btn_ok.setOnClickListener((View view) -> {
        Person p = new Person(et_name.getText().toString(), et_contact.getText().toString())

        comm.AddPerson(p);

});...
```

MainActivity implements the interface

```
...
@Override
public void AddPerson(Person p) {
    Frag1.getPerson(p);
}
```

Frag1

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Person> listPerson;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_person);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    return view;
}

public void getPerson(Person p) {
    listPerson.add(p);
    adapter = new AdapterRecV(getActivity(), listAluno);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the expected result by defining the List, and the Adapter as Static.